Ubuntu 20 fails to boot then gives error "blk update request critical target error /dev/sd*"
I updated Ubuntu t20LTS when it said system updates were available and pending. After the reboot, I get errors "FAILED TO START GNOME DISPLAY MANAGER" See systemctl status gdm.service for details. Then I attempted to update grub and still unable to get to a graphical display. Now getting the error in the title. I am unable to get past the boot options. No matter which kernel I choose. It gets stuck.. The drive it is referring to is my external Seagate 8tb backup drive. It gets mounted automatically at boot. My grub bootloader is on a 32gb sd card. This worked well for years. I am on an HP Proliant Gen3 ML310e server. I only use this server to run some vmware vms, nothing else. Please help.

Do you mean you are using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? The error is pretty clear a problem with that hard drive.

I don't think it's a hardware issue. Old issues have reappeared in the latest versions. I have not investigated in in depth, but encrypted drives get screwed up at boot time after an official upgrade, it is fixable but annoying.

Thank you for quick responses guys! to David, yes I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and clicked to install system updates (the ones that pop up periodically). To @Max Haase, I tend to agree. It is not encrypted but the external Seagate drive works fine. The system tries to catalog it at boot time even if I disconnect it. The second part of my problem is the grub boot loader got messed up and I am not sure how to get it back.

I installed a new hard drive after no luck with my recovery efforts. I unplugged the external drive getting errors. I booted to Ubuntu 22live disk, installed and ran boot-repair. I have a 16gb sd card for the grub. Here is the pastebin from boot-repair. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZVdcbVw2hf/  PLEASE HELP.

Do you still get FAILED TO START GNOME DISPLAY MANAGER?

@amar Yes I still get that error when I remove the Ubuntu Live disk. Since then, I had to do a complete reinstall of Ubuntu using the 22.04 LTS Live disk. Just did the default Ubuntu install. I use this machine to run Vmware VMs. So I then copied over my vm backups, installed vmware workstation 16 Pro,loaded my vms. I was never able to find out why I received the errors in the first place. It only occured IMMEDIATELY after attempting to install security updates for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS PLUS the upgrade to 22.04LTS. I am having new issues. I will open another question with those issues.

There was nothing wrong with the external target hard disk. It still works. It was mounted in /etc/fstab and still works with the new system. My investigations uncovered some things: HP Proliant servers does not support using microSD card for grub - although it will work. They also do not support non-RAID Ubuntu installations on the Proliant gen3 ML310e machines. You are on your own to figure it out. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has bugs when upgrading to 22.04 LTS with external hard drives mounted.
